# Como acessar itens específicos de uma <ul> com :nth-child()?

Tags: html, css, css3

Como eu posso acessar itens de 2 em 2 na minha lista usando o parâmetro :nth-child() ou se ficar mais fácil, acessar e customizar os itens pares?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode o seu pseudo seletor `nth-child` acrescentando a regra de par ou ímpar (`odd` ou `2n+1` e `even` ou `2n`) para customizar os elementos.

Para customizar customizar os itens pares ficaria:

```
li:nth-child(even) {
    // Seus estilos
}
```

Ou então:

```
li:nth-child(2n) {
    // Seus estilos
}
```

Preparei um JSFiddle para observar esse comportamento: http://jsfiddle.net/6428n8zm/

Dê uma olhada na documentação desse pseudo-selecto para ver todas as possíveis combinações que poderá fazer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child.

Answer (score 2):

Para customizar somente os itens pares você utilizaria o seguinte pseudo-seletor,

```
li:nth-child(even){} ou li:nth-child(2n){}
```

Para customizar somente os itens ímpares você utilizaria este outro,

```
li:nth-child(odd){} ou li:nth-child(2n+1){}
```

A função que o pseudo-seletor `nth-child` aceita é `An+B` (sendo `An` ou `B` opcionais), como assim?

Quando você coloca o valor de `(2n+1)`, automaticamente o CSS faz o cálculo, digamos que o `n` assumisse o valor de `0` (zero), logo `(2 * 0 + 1) = 1` (dois vezes zero é igual à zero, o resultado mais um é igual à um), então ele aplicaria os estilos declarados ao primeiro item da sua lista, logo em seguida o `n` é incrementado e passa a ter o valor de `1` (um), logo `(2 * 1 + 1) = 3` (dois vezes um é igual à dois, o resultado mais um é igual à três), então ele aplicaria os estilos declarados ao terceiro item da sua lista e assim por diante, sendo assim, a fórmula `(2n+1)` seleciona os elementos ímpares.

Já a fórmula `(2n)` irá fazer o mesmo processo, só que, sem a soma. Na primeira execução o `n` assume o valor de `0` (zero), então o cálculo é feito: `(2 * 0) = 0` (dois vezes zero é igual à zero), como não existe um item zero na lista, esse valor é desconsiderado e o `n` é incrementado passando a valer `1` (um), logo `(2 * 1) = 2` (dois vezes um é igual à dois), então os estilos declarados são aplicados ao item dois da sua lista e assim por diante, pelo fato de não ser acrescentado `1` ao resultado da multiplicação, o valor final será sempre um número par, fazendo com que a fórmula `(2n)` somente selecione elementos pares.

Veja que para a fórmula `(2n)` eu omiti o elemento `B` da função. Todos dois elementos são opcionais, sendo assim eu posso omitir o elemento `An` da função e declarar simplesmente o elemento `B`, da seguinte maneira: `li:nth-child(5){}`, como neste seletor não há nenhum cálculo a ser feito, então os estilos declarados são aplicados ao item de número que você declarou, neste caso, somente o item `5` será estilizado.